# Como passar o retorno de uma função que é uma tupla como argumentos para outra em Python?

Tags: python, funções, parâmetros, argumento

Estou tentando retornar múltiplos valores de uma função para outra com múltiplos parâmetros:

```
def chamar_ab():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b    #tupla

def soma(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Mas usar assim não parece possível:

```
soma(chamar_ab())
```

Como fazer isso funcionar usando tupla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que é isso que deseja:

```
def chamar_ab():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b

def soma(x, y):
    return x + y

print(soma(*chamar_ab()))
```

É o mesmo com listas e com chaves do dicionário, mas usando valores fica assim:

```
print(soma(*chamar_ab().values()))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/95AO5r). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DeconstructIntoArguments). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/DeconstructIntoArguments.py).

Este operador (`*`) faz uma sequência de dados serem transpostos como argumentos.